# Ошибка в параметризированном запросе

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть запрос и в него прилетают параметры. Мне нужно проверить чему равен параметр прилетевший ко мне. Делаю это вот так вот с помощью if

```
select da.act_year||' - '|| da.act_number 
       act_id,da.pipe_number,DA.DIAMETER,da.wall,
       da.steel,da.pipe_length pipe_len,da.pipe_weigth pipe_wei, 
       da.pipe_year,sr.id||' - '||sr.select_description prich_perev, 
       act_date,smena, da.dpr_confirm, da.dpr_note,
       (select FIO from intershop.auth_users where user_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(master_id, '^.*\\', null) and rownum = 1) FIO_Master,
       (select FIO from intershop.auth_users where user_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(inspector_id, '^.*\\', null) and rownum = 1) FIO_Inspector,
       (select FIO from intershop.auth_users where user_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(dpr_id, '^.*\\', null) and rownum = 1) FIO_Dpr
from   DEFECT_ACTS da 
left   join Sel_Rjs2 sr on da.id_prich_perev = sr.ID                               
where  DA.EDIT_STATE = 0 
and    (da.act_number >= :act_begin or :act_begin1 is null)
and    (da.act_number <= :act_end or :act_end1 is null)
and    (da.Diameter = :diam or :diam1 is null)
and    (da.wall = :wall or :wall1 is null)
and    (da.id_prich_perev = :prich_perev or :prich_perev1 is null)
and    (da.act_year = :act_year_ or :act_year_1 is null)
and    da.act_date between :DATA_START and :DATA_END 
and    (da.pipe_number = :p_n or :p_n1 is null)
and    (da.pipe_year = :p_e or :p_e1 is null)
and    (sr.dpr_sign_in_acts = :signature or :signature1 is null)
and    (case 
          when (:signature_status = 1 or signature_status = 2) 
          then (da.dpr_confirm) end
       ) = :signature_status 
or     signature_status1 is null
or     (case 
          when signature_status = 3 
          then (da.dpr_note) 
       end) = signature_status 
or     signature_status1 is null
order  by act_number desc
```

Но почему то ругается на строчку с if.

```
ORA-00904: "SIGNATURE_STATUS1": недопустимый идентификатор
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 25 Column: 81
```

Текст ошибки приведён. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Mike если можете подскажите пожалуйста в чём я ошибся. Не могу понять как нужно в данном случае пользоваться if. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: В оракле нельзя в sql запросе использовать if. Почитайте на тему `case ..when..then..end`

Comment: @lDrakonl сделал о же самое с case и та же самая ошибка.

Comment: @lDrakonl новый вариант запроса в теме вопроса.

Comment: @lDrakonl переписал запрос но снова ошибка. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: А что такое этот SIGNATURE_STATUS1 ? Я вижу прямо перед OR вы вроде проверяете его же но без 1 на конце. У вас в БД действительно 2 поля, одно с 1, а другое без ?

Comment: @Mike да так и есть. Только это параметры в fastreport.

Comment: А почему у остальных параметров есть двоеточия в начале, а у SIGNATURE_STATUS1 нет ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте в sql-запросах 
    `case .. when .. then .. else .. end;`
вместо того, что написано у Вас.
Конструкция
    `if .. else .. end if;` 
используется в хранимых процедурах, функциях и т.п.

Так же в sql символы `||` означают конкатенацию.

Вот пример:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) FROM DUAL P 
  WHERE 
  (CASE WHEN :PROBA = 4 OR :PROBA = 2 THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') END) = '2017'
  or
  (CASE WHEN :PROBA = 5 THEN '1' end) = '1';
```

Comment: Попробовал. У меня так же ругается почему то. В теме написано как я изменил запрос.

Comment: @Андрей, вместо || используйте or. Для `when :signature_status = 3 then da.dpr_note = :signature_status` используйте отдельный `case`

Comment: Переписал запрос в теме. Поменял как мне нужно и текст новой ошибки. А точнее ошибка та же но уже дальше на равно ругается не пойму что не так.

Comment: @Андрей, я немного не так написал. Сравните свой вариант и мой вариант, из примера. `case when (:signature_status = 1 or signature_status = 2) then (da.dpr_confirm = :signature_status or signature_status1 is null) end` надо сделать так `(case when (:signature_status = 1 or signature_status = 2) then (da.dpr_confirm) end) = :signature_status or signature_status1 is null`

Comment: Снова изменил запрос в теме и ошибку. Снова на что то ругается хотя сделал как у вас в примере. И разьве у signature_status1 не нужно тоже двоеточие поставить перед ним? Так кстати тоже попробовал и та же ошибка. Не подскажите в чём дело?

Comment: @Андрей, это значит, что такого идентификатора не существует (столбца или что-то еще). В первоначальной версии не было у вас идентификатора в примере. Откуда вы его сюда приписали не знаю.

Comment: `(case when (:signature_status = 1 or signature_status = 2) then (da.dpr_confirm) end) = :signature_status or signature_status1 is null` В изначально запросе `signature_status1` не было. Предполагаю, что это опечатка. Но в таком варианте условие всегда будет истинно.

Comment: @IDrakonl согласен. Я исправлял все по примерам Андрей. Я думаю, если написать вот так, то все должно заработать `(case when (:signature_status = 1 or :signature_status = 2) then (da.dpr_confirm) end) = :signature_status` .По аналогии и втрое условие надо привести к такому виду.

Answer (score 1):

**1:** В `Oracle sql` `or` нельзя написать как `||`. Палочки интерпретируются как конкатенация строк.

**2:** В результате выполнения `case` вернется значение из блоков внутри `then` или `else`. Написать в них сравнение, как у вас нельзя.

Я переписал `case` из вашего блока `where`, получилось так:

```
and 
case when :signature_status = 1 or :signature_status =2 then da.dpr_confirm 
     when :signature_status = 3 then da.dpr_note end = :signature_status
```

или еще можно вот так

```
and
(
  (:signature_status = 1 and da.dpr_confirm = :signature_status )
  or (:signature_status = 2 and da.dpr_confirm = :signature_status )
  or (:signature_status = 3 and da.dpr_note = :signature_status)
)
```

Получается, что в результате Ваше условие можно переписать вот так:

```
(da.dpr_confirm in (1, 2) or da.dpr_note=3)
```